# Java - Dividing two integers gives 0?

Tags: java

I might be missing something simple here, but when I divide two numbers that definately should not equal 0, I'm getting 0.

I've tried forcefully casting the values. SongDuration, originalSongDuration are integers. I need the percentage to be a float.

```
System.out.print("SongDuration: " + songDuration + " :: originalSongDuration: " + originalSongDuration + " :: percentage: " + (float) ((int)songDuration / (int)originalSongDuration));

[17:43:03 INFO]: SongDuration: 64746 :: originalSongDuration: 140746 :: percentage: 0.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm

Comment: @C.B. Java is strange :/ Thanks. Helps alot.

Comment: **Better duplicate target**: [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(float) ((float)songDuration / (float)originalSongDuration));
```

If you want a percent you should use floats. Diving one int by another will never give a decimal value. You are probably getting 0 returned because of this property of ints

Comment: FYI you don't need to cast both vars to float, just one will suffice. And as long as the variable where you're storing the result is a float, you don't need to cast the result. An alternative would be to multiply one of the vars by 1.0